# Rails Server Controller Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written a rails application but when running rails server I am getting following error

```
"syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' ...? ? render("result") : Your url have a problem );@output_buf... ... ^"

   </div>
  </div>
  <%= @links.present? ? render("result") : Your url have a problem %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose strings between `" "` or `' '` otherwise they will be treated as variables (or classes); `Your url have a problem` has no `""`, so that's causing the problem.

Try changing this line:

```
<%= @links.present? ? render("result") : Your url have a problem %>
```

to:

```
<%= @links.present? ? render("result") : "Your url have a problem" %>
```